# Why is this instance variable not incrementing (Python)?

Tags: python

I have implemented a Depth-first search algorithm, and using an instance variable called "call-count", I am trying to track how many recursions/comparisons are executed inside the code, i.e. how many times "searchDFS" is ran. Inside "searchDFS", the call_count variable defaults to the instance variable the first time searchDFS is ran, then it is passed down through every recursion. All of the other instance variables work fine, I am able to append to the top-level instance array "final_path" just fine, but it refuses to increment call_count.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do this?

The code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id, connections):
        self.id = id
        self.connections = connections


class DFS:
    def __init__(self):
        self.visited = {}
        self.nodes = []
        self.final_path = []
        self.call_count = 0

    def searchDFS(self, nodes, target, current, call_count=None, final_path=None, visited=None):
        if(visited == None): visited = self.visited
        if(final_path == None): final_path = self.final_path
        if(call_count == None): call_count = self.call_count
        
        call_count +=1 # <<< to increment every time searchDFS is ran
        
        if current in visited.keys(): 
            print(f'already visited node {current}')
            return 0
             
        else:
            print(f'current -> {current}')
            visited[current] = 1

            if(current == target): 
                print('found!')
                final_path.append(current)
                return True
            
            if(nodes[current].connections):
                for node in nodes[current].connections:
                    if(self.searchDFS(nodes, target, node.id, call_count, final_path, visited)):
                        final_path.append(current)
                        if(current == 0): 
                            print(final_path[::-1])
                            print(f'call count: {call_count}') # not incrementing !!! :(
                        return True
            return False
    def setup_graph(self):
        for x in range(0, 5):
            self.nodes.append(Node(x, []))
        self.nodes[0].connections = [self.nodes[1], self.nodes[2]]
        self.nodes[1].connections = [self.nodes[0], self.nodes[3]]
        self.nodes[2].connections = [self.nodes[0], self.nodes[4]]
        self.nodes[3].connections = [self.nodes[1]]
        self.nodes[4].connections = [self.nodes[2]]

    def print_graph(self):
        for node in self.nodes:
                print(f"node id: {node.id}")
                print("children: ")
                for childs in node.connections:
                    print(childs.id)

    def main(self):
        print('main() init')
        self.setup_graph()
        self.print_graph()
        self.searchDFS(self.nodes, 4, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DFS().main()
```

Comment: `call_count` is a local variable in `searchDFS`, unrelated to the instance attribute defined in `__init__`.

Comment: @chepner I set it to the instance attribute in the if statement, "call_count = self.call_count". This is set the first time it is run. I reference and append to "visited" and "final_path" just fine using the same exact kind of reference, why does it not work for call_count?

Comment: @ring0-collections Say that `call_count` and `xyz` are names that refer to the same int object.  When you do `call_count += 1`, no change is made to that object (in fact it's immutable). The name `call_count` is reassigned to refer to a new object whose value is 1 greater than that original int, while `xyz` still points to that original int.  So even if you do `call_count = self.call_count` at the start of the function, `self.call_count` doesn't change when you do `call_count += 1`.

Comment: @ring0-collections useful background: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @ring0-collections appending to a list is different: `xyz.append('foo')` doesn't change which object `xyz` refers to: rather, it performs an operation which modifies the internal data of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to @slothrop ([in-depth explanation](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html))

The difference comes down to "rebinding the name" versus "mutating the value"

Primitives are immutable in Python - They cannot be changed, only new ones created (and the variable name is re-bound to the new value):

```
x = 5
x = x + 1
```

The above creates a new block of memory with the new value, 6. Then, x rebinds to that new value. It is similar to how pointers work in C.

Unassigned values are automatically discarded by Python's garbage collector. The memory cell that was holding the '5' will be cleared, since it is no longer assigned to any variable.

Assignment never copies data, so assigning one variable to another won't make a second copy of the first, it just gives it 'directions' on where to look to find the value.

```
x = 5 # creates a value 5, with 'x' pointing to it
y = x # y is now pointing/bound to that same value, 5, as well
x = x + 1 # a new value, 6, is created, and x is "bound" to it
print(x) # outputs 6
print(y) # outputs 5
```

'y' is still "bound/looking" at the original '5'. There are also mutable values, like Lists. Lists contain a built-in function to append to themselves.

```
x = [1, 2]
y = x
x.append(3)
print(y) # outputs [1, 2, 3]
```

Since List is a class, it can have methods to change in-place, without having to create a completely new value like primitives.

In my code, when I assigned "call_count = self.call_count", I only pointed the value of "call_count" to the same value of instance variable "self.call_count". Incrementing "call_count" only assigns a new value for the *local variable* "call_count" without re-assigning the original *instance variable* "self.call_count". To fix this, I just made a function to update the instance's value, and bound a variable to that method inside my search function:

```
class DFS:
    def __init__(self):
        self.call_count = 0

    def increment_call_count(self):
        self.call_count += 1

    def searchDFS(self, counter=0, inc=None):
        if(inc == None): inc = self.increment_call_count # set once
        inc() # execute the function which "inc" is pointing at
        if(counter<5):
            self.searchDFS(counter + 1, inc)
        if(counter == 0): print(self.call_count) # prints 6 correctly

    def main(self):
        self.searchDFS()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DFS().main()
```

Since `inc` is only bound once to a single function, the 'value' of `inc` never changes, using it will just run that same function, which re-binds the original instance's variable to the new value.

Comment: Good explanation of how names and binding work! Your code looks like it should work - but one question. From your comments, are you thinking that doing `self.call_count += 1` directly wouldn't be ok, because `self` would refer to a different thing for each recursive call? In fact, you could happily just do `self.call_count += 1`, because `self` is the instance of the *class*, which is the same at every point in your recursion - you don't get a different `self` for every instantiation of the *function*. (Your recursive call is `self.searchDFS` rather than `someOtherObj.searchDFS`.)

Comment: @slothrop You're correct, I mixed up `self` when using it in an existing object, versus using it to pass a reference to an instance array. If `Node()` class had `searchDFS()` which calls something like: `for node in self.connections: node.searchDFS(target)`, where each connection is a `Node()` object, does the `self` switch to that object's class variables? In that case, do I have to explicitly pass the first node's `final_path` and `visited` class variable into those recursions? And what method is faster, re-indexing that one array, or traversing through the objects' own node connections?

Comment: @slothrop What I mean is, rather than running a function that searches the original array (inside the first DFS instance), I could just have that function inside the Node class and make it search through its own connections. All those nodes still need a reference to the first node's `final_path`, `call_count`, and `visited`, but they also need a reference to their own `self.id`, so I'm not certain how `self` would work here. I haven't figured out how to do this without passing those "persistent" values into the recursion, because `self` will just reference each node's own empty class variables

Comment: Passing `call_count` and `visited` into the recursively-called function should be OK, as those need to be shared across different branches of the recursive 'tree'. You could maybe have these as two keys in the same dictionary, for convenience. For `final_path`, rather than passing a mutable object around to be written into, an alternative is to have `searchDFS`, instead of returning True when it has a path to the target, return what that path is. Then the caller node appends its own ID to the path returned by the callee, and passes that back up to *its* caller.